# How to have the same function access in controller than views

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Some functions (for example helpers functions) in my view are not accessible in my controller..
I KNOW that I can include Helpers in my controller to have access BUT if this helper function call another helper function I have a MethodError !

Example

In my View:

```rb
...
<%= myHelperFunction %>
```

In the helper:

```rb
module Helper
  def myHelperFunction
    myHelper2Function # it's a call of another helper
  end
end
```

In the controller:

```rb
  include Helper

def myRouteAction
  myHelperFunction # no method error
  Helper.myHelperFunction # no method error

  myHelperFunction # i can call it BUT i've a no method error on the second function called
                   # myHelper2Function
end
```

Comment: What would be the reason to need the same function in two different places that handle different logic? Can you explain further what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot `include MyHelper` inside of the controller action, you'll have to add this line outside of action, like below:

```
include MyHelper
def index
  myHelperFunction1
end
```

Now, let's say you've 2 Helpers - `ArticlesHelper` and `PostsHelper`, then you can do something like this:

```
# articles_helper.rb
module ArticlesHelper
  # Need to include this helper since you'll call `mnop` method from PostsHelper
  include PostsHelper

  def abcd
    efgh
  end

  def efgh
    "Hello from EFGH in ArticlesHelper"
  end

  def ijkl
    # calls `mnop` method from PostsHelper
    mnop
  end
end


# posts_helper.rb
module PostsHelper

  def mnop
    "Hello from mnop from PostsHelper"
  end
end
```

Then in any of your controller you can do something like this:

```
include ArticlesHelper
def myRouteAction
  @hello = abcd
  @hello2 = ijkl
end
```

Then in your views, do something like this:

```
<%= @hello %>
# "Hello from EFGH in ArticlesHelper"

<%= @hello2 %>
# "Hello from mnop from PostsHelper"
```

I think the above example illustrates all the scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

you can directly call helper method in controller without include module.

```
def myRouteAction
  helpers.myHelperFunction
end
```